# what is the line number of an ienumerable exception when it is lazily evaluated?

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, ienumerable, lazy-evaluation

I created this code to see, but I'm assuming that the enumerable is *not* being lazily evaluated when I test it.

```
    public void EnumerableExceptionTest_CanOnlyBeTestedByInspectingError()
    {
        var ints = GetIntsButReallyThrowError();  // error occurs here.
        var y = 10;
        var z = 11;
        foreach(var i in ints) // error *could* be on this line, but not in my tests.
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i+y+z);
        }

    }
    private IEnumerable<int> GetIntsButReallyThrowError()
    {
        var x = true;
        if (x)
        {
            throw new Exception("Threw this on purpose.");
        }
        else
        {
            return new int[]{1,2,3};
        }
    }
```

Is it possible though the error would not occur until it is lazily evaluated, and thus that the error line number would be that of the foreach loop?

*Note, this may be useful to keep in mind while debugging if the methodname isn't on the line that the callstack says it's on.  It doesn't necessarily mean that your code / pdbs are out of date :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the structure may or may not be evaluated lazily, but your method is executed as soon as it is called. Since your Exception is hit before anything is returned, that execution throws.

You could try this instead. It takes advantage of the `yield` keyword to lazily build the result on the fly:

```
private IEnumerable<int> GetIntsButReallyThrowError()
{
    yield return 1;
    throw new Exception("Threw this on purpose.");
}
```

Comment: Note that you could throw the exception before the first `yield` and it still won't throw an exception when the method is called; only when you try to get the first value.